# Flutter android flavors generate apk

Tags: android, flutter, dart, google-play

I am trying to set up Android flavors with flutter.

I have two entry points.

```
lib/main_prod.dart
lib/main_dev.dart
```

I have also added the following to my gradle file

```
flavorDimensions "version"
productFlavors {
    prod {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
    }
    dev {
        dimension "version"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        versionNameSuffix " Dev"
    }
}
```

Now I am trying to generate two separate apk which I can use to publish to the Google Play Store.

[image]

I go on Android Studio and try generate these.

However I get this error.

[image]

Android Studio is still trying to look for the main.dart file, however, for my two flavors they are main_prod.dart and main_dev.dart. How do I tell Android Studio to look for the approperiate main file depending on the flavor im trying to get the apk file for.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

To build apk or appbundle(to publish to the playstore) for each flavor you can use the commands(recommended) instead of using android studio.

For `prod` you can use:

APK

```
flutter build apk --flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart
```

App Bundle

```
flutter build appbundle --flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart
```

and for `dev`

APK

```
flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

App Bundle

```
flutter build appbundle --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. For me "appBundle" didn´t work. It must be "appbundle" instead.

Comment: How to generate app bundle with keys(Play app signing)?

Comment: @BLB for generating appbundle, try flutter build appbundle -t lib/main_dev.dart

Comment: @jideGuru is there any way to generate build for iOS platform while including param "-t lib/main.dart"

Comment: @JideGuru how we can set main.dart file to their respective build variants instead of this commands?

Answer (score 5):

The above command will work for release builds, but for the debug builds, you may need to use this command:

```
flutter build apk -t lib/main_dev.dart --flavor=dev --debug
```

Otherwise, it may throw this error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:validateSigningDevRelease'.
> Keystore file not set for signing config release

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDevRelease'...                     6.6s
Gradle task assembleDevRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply for prod environment `flutter build apk -t lib/main_prod.dart --release` for release apk and `flutter build apk -t lib/main_prod.dart --debug` for debug apk should work.

Answer (score 0):

This is very simple use below command

```
flutter build apk --[BuildType] --flavor [Flavor Name]
```

For Release

```
flutter build apk --release --flavor production
```

For Debug

```
flutter build apk --debug --flavor production
```