# Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under C:\......\build, but the tool couldn't find it

Tags: android, flutter, dart, build, android-productflavors

I'm tring to build my flutter app on android in CMD and got message (in the subject) but app works properly.
The build proccess was OK and the problem started afer I changed one of the dependencies.

I have 2 flavors.
The android studio build create app without errors.

Any idea?

Comment: I found the answer in
tthe following case
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63134797/flutter-android-flavors-generate-apk

Answer (score 1):

It's possible that the command is unable to find the build path to generate the APK. You can run these commands in the Terminal built into Android Studio.

For building APK for prod

```
flutter build apk --flavor prod -t lib/main_prod.dart
```

For building APK for dev

```
flutter build apk --flavor dev -t lib/main_dev.dart
```